# What are colima deamon settings for connection from intellij

Tags: docker, colima

I have installed [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) and it works great.
I am using `ssh://localhost:60006` to connect to it from visual studio Docker plugin but was not able to connect to it from jetbrains Docker plugin.

Does anyone know what settings should I use?

Comment: "Docker daemon connection option for Colima" feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-288461

Comment: colima integration has been added to 2022.2 version: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2022.2+EAP+%28222.2270.28+build%29+Release+Notes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer: under `~/.colima/` there is the socket file `docker.sock`.

In order to configure intellij - I added tcp connection and in the API url I put: `unix:/Users/{myuser}/.colima/docker.sock`.

Answer (score 2):

Now IntelliJ 2022.2 [supports colima](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html#enable_docker)! Enjoy... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`colima status` will give you this information.
Also given on `colima start`

Answer (score 1):

With new versions of IntellijIDEA (2023.1.1 in my case)

Following the next image, right click in number two option and select `Edit Configuration`

[image]